# Android studio - Is there a hotkey to "Replace All" without having to use mouse?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm on mac and press cmd + R to bring up the "Find/Replace" tab and was wondering if there's a hotkey to select the "Replace all" option w/o having to use the mouse. I tried enter and it just replaces the current selected word. Cmd+Enter, Option+Enter, Ctrl+Enter all didn't work. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that can be done, but you may want to look into "Refactoring".

Just select the word and press Shift+F6. This'll change the word and all it's instances in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Eclipse (Mac OS X)` keymap, and `Alt + a` does `Replace All` operation.

I checked with `Eclipse`, `default for macOS`, worked here as well.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Haven't been able to find a hotkey for "ReplaceAll" as you mentioned. But in order to ReplaceAll without mouse what I do, in Windows, is type in the word to find first and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to select all occurrences and then simply type the new word.

For Mac it seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

This may not be the solution you were looking for, but might come in handy for someone

Answer (score 0):

`option + a` does a Replace All when using the [Sublime Text (MacOS) keymap](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12551-sublime-text-keymap/versions) as well (similar to what @alex-sunder-singh said)